# Making a recursive method that labels "organisms"

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array

I need to develop a method that can accept a 2D array and will go through the array to check for "organisms" that are defined by an asterisk in the array location. One "organism" is made up of all the asterisks that are neighbors to each other in the up/down and left/right directions, but not the diagonals. My professor recommends that I create 2 methods, one that returns the number of organisms as well as calls the other method that is supposed to be a recursive method that labels the "organisms". I have started a setup for the first method (below) and have made it so it can accept arrays of length 0 and 1, but I am unsure as to how I setup the rest of the 1st method, 2nd recursive method as well as how I should call it.

```java
public static int howManyOrganisms(char[][] image) {
    int organismCount = 0;
    for (int row = 0; row < image.length; row++) {
        for (int col = 0; col < image[row].length; col++) {
            if (image.length == 0) {
                return organismCount;
            } else if (image.length == 1 && image[row].length == 1) {
                if (image[row][col] == '*') {
                    organismCount += 1;
                    return organismCount;
                } else {
                    return organismCount;
                }
            } else {
                return 0;
            }
        }
    }
    return organismCount;
}
```

Comment: I'd recommend editing your question to include a couple of sample inputs along with the expected outputs of those inputs to better clarify what you're attempting to accomplish.

Comment: call the 2nd method just anything, then wait until a proper name comes up and refactor.

Comment: I have posted a better version of the question with sample input and output here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64960511/how-to-label-groups-within-a-2d-array-using-recursion